# twitter bootstrap tooltip is misplaced

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

Please take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtaVs/1/)

I gave position absolute to a question-sign icon with `top:0; right: -42px;` therefore the element that shows tooltip is outside of `row`. I think this has caused tooltip to not get proper width or misplace the tooltip content and tooltip content trapped within `row-fluid`. as you can see arrow position is fine.

**update**: I'd place `?` icon next to textarea and textarea fill its parent width and aligned right. here is another [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mtaVs/7/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Specify `body` as a container for a tooltip ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mtaVs/9/)):

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    container: 'body'
});
```